# How to manipulate Java's BigIntegers

Tags: java, biginteger, modulo

I would like to do this with BigInteger values:

```
 while (Math.pow(A, n) <= factorial(B)) {
    if (factorial(B)%Math.pow(A, n) == 0) {
        powerA.add(n);
    }
    n++;
}
```

I already managed to do a factorial function with BigInteger but I can't figure out how to make the test condition "if".

Yet I have:

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(A).pow(n);
while (factorial(B).compareTo(bi) == 1) {
    if (factorial(B).mod(bi) == 0) {
        powerA.add(n);
    }
    n++;
}
```

Comment: `BigInteger::remainder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java `BigInteger` is a class, in the same way that `String` or any user-defined object is a class, so `==` is going to compare for identity, which is not what you want. You need `.equals`.

```
if (factorial(B).mod(bi).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
  ...
}
```

It's also worth noting that most `BigInteger` methods do *not* mutate the existing value and instead return a new one. So to add to `powerA`, you want to do

```
powerA = powerA.add(n);
```